# Tenancy for laravel - How can I use the central tables?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, multi-tenant

Hello I am using this package https://tenancyforlaravel.com/. My question is how can I access the central tables using a model? What currently I am using is through the db connection method.

I based it here https://tenancyforlaravel.com/docs/v2/central-app/. But I am using v3 and I cant find its method on v3.

This is what currently I am using.
`$courses = DB::connection('mysql')->table('courses')->get();`

What I want to do is
`$courses = Course::all();`

Comment: How is your central model defined and how is your database config? We can simply add `protected $connection = 'central';` to the model and the connection defaults to the central connection.

Comment: after defining it, i can use this method `$courses = Course::all();`?

Comment: Yes, all of our central database models have this attribute. We made an abstract class called CentralModel where this is attribute is set, so we don't have to set it for each central model individually...

Comment: Hmm I cant still use the function `$courses = Course::all();` @Aless55

Comment: We used this approach since laravel 7, how does your config look like?

Comment: I just fixed it @Aless55. I used the trait `Stancl\Tenancy\Database\Concerns\CentralConnection` in the model. In that way you can use the model to be universal

Comment: This is the same as setting $connection = "YourCentralDBConfigName"; which by documentation should be central, it might be possible that your config is not the same as mine :) Thats why I asked you to share your config